# Managing memory block created with new char* but allocated to std::vector elements with custom allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have been working on a project to store vectors in a contiguous manner. My current setup has a `custom allocator` for `std::vector` that contains a reference to a `memory management object`.

- The `memory management object` contains a `char*` pointing to its current buffer and an `std::vector` where I push the `char *` for a buffer once that buffer is full.
- Each `char*` buffer is created by the `memory management object` with a `new` call.
- The `std::vectors` that use the custom allocator are wrapped in a `SmallVector` class.
- The `SmallVectors` are created through calls to their class constructors, which don't contain any `new` or `malloc` statements.

I `delete` the `char*'s` I created with a `new` in the destructor of the `memory  management object` by looping through the vector containing the `char *s` and `delete-ing` each one. Will everything else take care of itself? Even if it will, is that proper or are there tighter memory  management steps I could take for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each char* buffer is created by the memory management object with a new call.

That should probably be a call to `operator new` ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)) to get uninitialized memory (unless you know that's what you want).

> Will everything else take care of itself?

From what you've posted, yes. Just make sure your allocator is CopyConstructable (basically, `allocator a; allocator b(a);` works).

> Even if it will, is that proper or are there tighter memory management steps I could take for this scenario?

You could use `std::unque_ptr` for automatic deallocation if you stick to `new`, or you could use `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter if you use `operator new`.